# Sequalise: TypeError: Class constructor Modal cannot be invoked without 'new' (typescript)

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am using typescript in node and it works great in development mode by running my index.ts with ts-node using the following command.

```
ts-node src/index.ts
```

but when I transpile my typescript code into es6 and run index.js file using the simple node command

```
node dist/index.js
```

it throws the error that

```
/home/ubuntu/Projects/projects/Servers/test-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:486
  this.importCache[importPath] = defineCall(this, DataTypes);
                                 ^
 TypeError: Class constructor Modal cannot be invoked without 'new'
at Sequelize.import (/home/ubuntu/Projects/projects/Servers/test-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:486:38)
```

below is my tsconfig.json file

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {   
  "target": "ES2015",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "outDir": "./dist",  
  "rootDir": "./src",
  "strict": true, 
  "moduleResolution": "node", 
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true 
 }
}
```

I tried everything solutions available related to this error but nothing works for me and still getting this error.

this is my sequelize index file.

```
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import config from "../config";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path"

export default class Modal {
public db: any = {};
private config = new config().config
constructor() {
    this.registerSchemaInDB();
}
private sql: any = new Sequelize(
    'mysql://' + this.config.database.username + ':' + this.config.database.password + '@localhost:3306/' + this.config.database.name, {
    dialect: "mysql",
    host: this.config.database.host
});
private registerSchemaInDB = () => {
    fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
        .filter((file) => {
            return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.ts") ;
        })
        .forEach((file) => {
            console.log(file);
            let model = this.sql.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
            this.db[model.name] = model;
        });

    Object.keys(this.db).forEach((modelName) => {
        if ("associate" in this.db[modelName]) {
            this.db[modelName].associate(this.db);
        }
    });
    this.db.sequelize = this.sql
}
```

}

> Node version v12.14.0
>
> Sequelize version 5.21.3

thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same error came to me, when i was trying to build my project using

> tsc -p .

build command it works fine totally fine. but throws the same error while running build project

but i figure out my mistake. you just need to refactor your **fs.readdirSync** condition.

just replace it with below code

```
fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
        .filter((file) => {
            return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.ts") && (file !== "index.js");
        })
        .forEach((file) => {
            console.log(file);
            let model = this.sql.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
            this.db[model.name] = model;
        });
```

what you did wrong is you only filter **index.ts** file you also have to make check for **index,js**